# How to use purrr to programatically cat and/or print janitor tabyl output

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr, janitor

Say you're using the `tidyverse` to nest() a select group of categorical variables:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)

nested_df <- mpg %>%
  select(manufacturer, class) %>%
  gather(variable, value) %>%
  group_by(variable) %>%
  nest()

nested_df
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  variable     data              
  <chr>        <list>            
1 manufacturer <tibble [234 x 1]>
2 class        <tibble [234 x 1]>
```

Now we can add a new column which contains the output from [`janitor::tabyl`](https://github.com/sfirke/janitor):

```
nested_df %>%
  mutate(
    table_output = map(data, ~ tabyl(.$value))
  )

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  variable     data               table_output    
  <chr>        <list>             <list>          
1 manufacturer <tibble [234 x 1]> <tabyl [15 x 3]>
2 class        <tibble [234 x 1]> <tabyl [7 x 3]>
```

Questions:

1. How can we print or walk through the output to get both the `variable` name and the `table_output`?
2. Is there a better approach (e.g. using `split` instead of `group_by %>% nest`?

---

Something like printing the following...

```
Variable is: manufacturer

Tabyl Output:

    .$value  n    percent
       audi 18 0.07692308
  chevrolet 19 0.08119658
      dodge 37 0.15811966
       ford 25 0.10683761
 ...more rows...
    mercury  4 0.01709402
     nissan 13 0.05555556
    pontiac  5 0.02136752
     subaru 14 0.05982906
     toyota 34 0.14529915
 volkswagen 27 0.11538462


Variable is: class

Tabyl Output:

    .$value  n    percent
    2seater  5 0.02136752
    compact 47 0.20085470
    midsize 41 0.17521368
    minivan 11 0.04700855
     pickup 33 0.14102564
 subcompact 35 0.14957265
        suv 62 0.26495726
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `pwalk`, `cat`, and `print`. The input to `pwalk` is a data.frame (list of lists) containing only the `variable` and `table_output` columns. Similar to `pmap`, `pwalk` walks through each element of both columns simultaneously and are being referenced by `.x` and `.y` in the anonymous function. Different from `pmap`, `pwalk` executes the code without returning any output. This is useful when we only want the side-effect of the code execution:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)

nested_df <- mpg %>%
  select(manufacturer, class) %>%
  gather(variable, value) %>%
  group_by(variable) %>%
  nest()

nested_df %>%
  mutate(
    table_output = map(data, ~ tabyl(.$value))
  ) %>%
  select(-data) %>%
  pwalk(~{
    cat(paste0('Variable is: ', .x, '\n\nTabyl Output: \n\n')) 
    print(.y)
    cat('\n\n')
  })
```

To print strings, we use `cat` to avoid the `[1]` in front. To print the table output, we use `print`. `"\n"`s are added to pad blank lines for readability.

**Output:**

```
Variable is: manufacturer

Tabyl Output: 

    .$value  n    percent
       audi 18 0.07692308
  chevrolet 19 0.08119658
      dodge 37 0.15811966
       ford 25 0.10683761
      honda  9 0.03846154
    hyundai 14 0.05982906
       jeep  8 0.03418803
 land rover  4 0.01709402
    lincoln  3 0.01282051
    mercury  4 0.01709402
     nissan 13 0.05555556
    pontiac  5 0.02136752
     subaru 14 0.05982906
     toyota 34 0.14529915
 volkswagen 27 0.11538462


Variable is: class

Tabyl Output: 

    .$value  n    percent
    2seater  5 0.02136752
    compact 47 0.20085470
    midsize 41 0.17521368
    minivan 11 0.04700855
     pickup 33 0.14102564
 subcompact 35 0.14957265
        suv 62 0.26495726
```

Comment: Could tabyl also be used to show working as row wise total instead of columnwise